# How to exempt case sensitivity of data structures values

Tags: python, data-structures

How to retrieve list values from existing list regardless it's in upper case or lowercase.

```
langlist =['python','java','javascript','c#','rubi','html','Python']

langlist.count('Python')
1

langlist.index('java')
1

langlist.index('Java')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ValueError: 'Java' is not in list
```

Comment: Create a copy of the list where everything is lowercase. Or create your own list subclass that lowercases everything while doing comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it this way, since the item "java" would be different from "Java".

If if you converted your query to lowercase (or equivalently uppercase), the items of the list would still be case sensitive.

What you could do is to manually search the list, and for every item, convert it to its lowercase counterpart - convert the query to lowercase as well, and compare them to find out whether they are equal or not.

Example:

```
langlist =['python','java','javascript','c#','rubi','html','Python']
query = "Java"
for item in langlist:
    if(item.lower() == query.lower()):
        print("Original item: " + item)
```